# masonry on bootstrap elements got bumped down to new row

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

The nature of the elements are that each one will be varied in height (due to image and the title) and its height is unknown before applying masonry. Though the width of each element is fixed with .col-lg-3.

On the rendered page where each row has 4 elements, the 5 element is visually on a row on its own and the 6, 7, 8 got pushed down to 3rd row.

**html code**

```
<div class="section-details">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="">
      <div class="masonry" id="elements" data-reference="0">
      <!-- elements will be pulled over dynamically -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the content of each new element is wrapped in something like the following

```
<div class="col-lg-3 element">
</div>
```

**css**
    .element {
      padding: 10px 10px 0px;
    }

**javascript code**

```
// layout the elements
var layout = function(elements, $container, selector) {
  $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: selector,
      columnWidth: selector,
      isAnimated: true,
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
      }
    }).append(elements).masonry('appended', elements, true);
  });
};
```

and it's got called in the following way

```
layout(elements, $('#elements'), '.element');
```

So anything could go wrong here?

Comment: Why are 'itemSelector, columnWidth' both "selector"?

Comment: Good catch, I added that line when debugging the issue, forgot to remove it. It's still the same behavior after removing that option :(

Comment: A jsfiddle or a link would help

Comment: Debugged into the masonry source code and figured out the cause, it's how the elements got prepared that matters - each of the element that got pushed to the elements array should be an HTMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

Debugged into the masonry source code and figured out the cause, it's how the elements got prepared that matters - each of the element that got pushed to the elements array should be an HTMLElement. And once I got that fixed, the issue was gone.